# On Cell Change program suddenly stopped working VBA

Tags: vba, onchange

Edit: Making this way simpler.
Edit2: Changed Target.Application to Application

The following code should detect a change in any cell in column A, and change the value of the adjacent cell in column B to "Success".

This was working, and now it isn't.

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    If Not Intersect(ActiveCell, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Success"

    End If

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Probably needs an error handler to make sure `.EnableEvents = True` is always executed regardless of an error.

Comment: There's some amount of `ActiveSheet` references and calls to Range/Cells with no qualifying worksheet object attached.  Once you've fixed the current issue you should also think about fixing those, or your code may well be still error-prone.

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks! I was hoping someone would chime in with some advice like this.

Comment: You set to false `With Target.Application` and set `With Application` to true. Did you do so deliberately?

Comment: @Toni No, I was futzing around with something I read on stack exchange. I was just trying anything I could, really, to see if it would make a difference. I'll switch that back.

Answer (score 0):

Should look more like this:

```vb
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Dim rng As Range, c As Range
    
    Set rng = Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A:A"))
    
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo haveError 'turn on error handling
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each c In rng.Cells 'need to handle a multi-cell update
            c.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Success"
        Next c
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If

    Exit Sub 'normal exit

haveError:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Application.EnableEvents = True 'ensure events aren't left turned off
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately this still doesn't seem to do anything! I'm baffled--this code was working fine not so long ago.

Comment: Works for me.  You have it in the worksheet code module, and events are turned on?